# how to disable timestamps from perl warn command

Tags: perl

how do I get rid of the timestamp and script name from warn():

```
[Mon Jun 12 10:31:38 2017] db_insert.pl:  "subjects": ["Government - Comparative", "Politics / Current Events"], "revision": 4}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the line that produces the timestamp.

Comment: Is this a command line program or some kind of web application? How is it deployed? How is this line generated? Where is it displayed? If you want people to help you for free, then it's useful to give them as much information as possible.

Comment: Looks like Log4Perl or similar.

Comment: `warn` doesn't normally add timestamps, but you might have a `$SIG{__WARN__}` handler that adds the timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

That message isn't generated by Perl's `warn`

If I generate a generic warning message, it looks like this

```
$ perl -e 'warn "Warning message"'
Warning message at -e line 1.
```

So it is your program that is building strings and passing them to `warn`. You have to look at that to remove the time stamp